# Django Model Queryset - Inserir registro se não existir com apenas uma consulta

Tags: python, django

Estou começando a utilizar o django e o seu ORM e me surgiu uma dúvida.

Como posso verificar se o registro existe no banco e se não existir já efetuar a inserção do mesmo? Isso com apenas uma consulta ao banco de dados.

Encontrei varios exemplos na internet, mas ambos acabam fazendo uma segunda consulta ou `.count()`, e eu queria evitar isso.

Eu tenho feito dessa forma (com try e DoesNotExist), mas não sei se é a melhor opção visto que o try se destina a validar exceções:

```
try:
    cdfield = CadCliFieldValue.objects.filter(
        cadcli_id=json_data['cadcli'], 
        cadcli_field_id=json_data['cadcli_field_id'], 
        status=1
    ).get()
    cdfield.value = json_data['value']
    cdfield.save()
except CadCliFieldValue.DoesNotExist:
    cdfield = CadCliFieldValue()
    cdfield.value = json_data['value']
    cdfield.cadcli_id = json_data['cadcli']
    cdfield.cadcli_field_id = json_data['cadcli_field_id']
    cdfield.created_by = request.user
    cdfield.save()
```

**Editado:**
Para tenta explicar melhor o que estou tentando evitar, segue exemplo de como a documentação e os exemplos que encontrei na internet me recomenda a fazer:

```
cdfield = CadCliFieldValue.objects.filter(
    cadcli_id=json_data['cadcli'], 
    cadcli_field_id=json_data['cadcli_field_id'], 
    status=1
)

if cdfield.exists(): # Aqui ele fez 1 consulta ao banco
    cdfield = cdfield.get() # Aqui mais uma consulta (XXXX)
    cdfield.value = json_data['value']
    cdfield.save() # aqui um update
else:
    cdfield = CadCliFieldValue()
    cdfield.value = json_data['value']
    cdfield.cadcli_id = json_data['cadcli']
    cdfield.cadcli_field_id = json_data['cadcli_field_id']
    cdfield.created_by = request.user
    cdfield.save() # Aqui apenas um update
```

Eu queri eliminar a segunda consulta com o get(), até tentei tirar o `cdfield = cdfield.get()` e só chamar o save(), mas se eu não fizer a chamada ao método get, o python me retorna essa erro:

> 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'save'

Comment: A pergunta parece bem interessante, mas não entendi o que quer fazer. Tem como editar a pergunta e detalhar um pouco mais? pretende inserir um dado padrão? Evitar duplicação?

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta, não será um valor padrão, os dados sempre vem do formulário e existe sim a necessidade de validar duplicidades, tanto que faço isso nos filtros com campos que também vem do formulário

Comment: @FernandoTholl utilizar um index e setar a coluna como `unique` resolve o problema? Se for um conjunto de atributos o django também fornece uma função helper pra isso. O `unique_together`. Que pela descrição do seu problema parece ser o que você precisa. Se já tentou essas abordagens poderia explicar por que elas não resolvem o seu problema?

Comment: @Danizavtz, agradeço a resposta. Eu não tenho problemas com os filtros da minha consulta, inclusive se eu criar um indice composto pelos dois campos devo ter o mesmo retorno do django informando que o registro já existe no banco, o que eu quero eliminar ali no segundo código são as duas consultas que ele faz no banco, uma para verificar se existe e outra para retornar o objeto preenchido para que eu possa atualizar.

Comment: Só complementando o comentário, o meu primeiro código faz exatamente o que eu quero, porém com o try except, eu gostaria de uma outra abordagem, sem o uso do except CadCliFieldValue.DoesNotExist

Answer (score -2):

O método `get_or_create` faz exatamente o que você precisa. Ele funciona retornando uma tupla com o objeto e um *boolean*, se o objeto existir ele é retornado e o boolean vem `False`, caso não exista ele é criado e o boolean vem `True`, é bem simples de usar.

Segue [`link da doc`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)